# Uniqueness of a minimal polynomial $m_T(x))$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, minimal-polynomials

> Let $T : V \rightarrow V$ be a linear operator on an $n$-dimensional
>   vector space $V$ over a field $F$ (resp. $A \in  M_n(F))$. Let $m(x)$
>   be a minimal polynomial of $T$ (resp. $A$).
>
> In particular, there is exactly one minimal polynomial of $T$ (resp.
>    $A$) and will be denoted as \begin{equation*} m_T(x) := m(x)
>  ~~~(\text{resp}: m_A(x) := m(x)) \end{equation*} **Further, if $A =
>  [T]_B$ (the representation matrix), then $m_T(x) = m_A(x)$.**

I have some trouble understanding the proof of the last part of the question. Firstly, does the minimal polynomial of $T$ means the minimal polynomial of $[T]_C$ for where $C$ is any basis of $V$? i am a bit confused.

The most i did was let $m_T(x)$ be the min polynomial of $T$, then we have $$m_T(T) = 0 \implies [m_T(T)]_B = 0 \implies m_T([T]_B) = 0 \implies m_T(A) = 0$$ But the notation is confusing and i cannot seem to show that $m_T(x) = m_A(x)$. Please help